# Cannot come out from the play store internal beta testing

Tags: react-native, google-play-services, beta-testing, google-play-internal-testing

[image: Check out this image]

We have uploaded an update of our existing app (WASFAT) as internal testing build. We can access it successfully.

Now I want to leave from the internal testing and want to access the live build.

There is not leave button the playstore wasfat page. Please have a look at the attached image.

When we have released beta version, we had that leave button. But in the internal release, we don't have it.

How can I get out from this internal testing mode? How can I access the original live build? Also I don't want to remove my id from play console internal testing.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. Not without removing yourself from the internal testers list. You will want to have 2 play ids, one for production and one for internal track testing. At least, that's how I've always done it - if there is a way to do what you are asking, I would love to find out what it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, you can opt-out of internal testing with the same link you used to enter in the internal testing program. Also, you need to remove your email from internal tester. However, It will take some time to be able to access live mode again

Comment: yeah, we need to remove the id from internal testing to get out from it. But after production build is live, I can access production build as internal testing mode itself.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I have found is to just switch to a different account within play store.

1. Open play store afresh
2. On top right, tap your account icon (or where ever it is located)
3. Click the drop down and tap "Add another account"
4. Later on it is just a matter of selecting an account, no password entry needed if done before.

The advantage of this is that you don't have to wait for Googles services to register that you have disabled a testing account. When you need to enable the testing account you will have to wait again. So this is pretty nifty for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the following steps to get it resolved:

1. Uninstall the Beta app
2. Leave the internal tester program using the same link using which you accepted the internal testing invitation.
3. Remove the email from the list of internal testing users in the Google Play console.
4. Go into the device settings > Apps & notifications > Google Play store
5. Click on Storage and cache > Clear Storage and cache

Answer (score -1):

I'm reliably able to restart my phone, and have changes to beta status reflected immediately.